# Breadcrumbs in Angular don't show my children node details

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm a beginner in Angular, and use BreadCrumb in my project. I have no problem with other pages, but when I want to show my child node details, I can only see the product id.
My project is [here](https://github.com/arashyazdani/ApiTest), and this is my code.

`core.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestErrorComponent } from './test-error/test-error.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { ServerErrorComponent } from './server-error/server-error.component';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BreadcrumbModule } from 'xng-breadcrumb';
import { SectionHeaderComponent } from './section-header/section-header.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavBarComponent, TestErrorComponent, NotFoundComponent, ServerErrorComponent, SectionHeaderComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    BreadcrumbModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
      preventDuplicates: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [NavBarComponent, SectionHeaderComponent]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

`shop.routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ShopComponent } from './shop.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details/product-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ShopComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: ProductDetailsComponent, data: { breadCrumb: { alias: 'productDetails' } }}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ShopRoutingModule { }
```

`product-details.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from '../../shared/models/product';
import { ShopService } from '../shop.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'xng-breadcrumb';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.scss']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  product: IProduct;

  constructor(private shopService: ShopService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private bcService: BreadcrumbService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadProduct();
  }

  loadProduct() {
    this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(product => {
      this.product = product;
      this.bcService.set('@productDetails', product.name);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

I gave [my project link](https://github.com/arashyazdani/ApiTest) to check all of my code if you need it. Thanks for the help!

This happened when I debugged my project on chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you have a typing error,

in shop-routing-module.ts it should be breadcrumbnot breadCrumb

```
data: { breadcrumb: { alias: 'productDetails' } },
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot.